# how to run same set of scenarios in 2 backgrounds in behave python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bdd

I have 2 backgrounds for my login page 1) in which the user accepts the cookie 2) user declines cookies.

```
Feature:ORG_LOGIN|Login action with organization ID after accepting cookies

  Background:
    Given User is on login page
    When user accepts the cookies
    And User navigates to organization tab
    And clicks on password eye


#  @positive
#  Scenario:Login with valid credentials
#    When User enters valid Organization ID, username and password
#    And hits Login button
#    Then Dashboard page is displayed
```

After this the same set of scenarios(8 in number) need to be tested.

I am using behave 1.2.6 with python 3.11.0 and selenium 4.6.0

```
Since there can be only 1 background per feature file, I tried copying all scenarios into another feature file with different background. I get following error
```

behave.step_registry.AmbiguousStep: @given('User is on login page') has already been defined in
existing step @given('User is on login page') at steps/login_ac.py:8

Any thoughts how can I implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing duplicate implementations of the steps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).